# Extracting info on polygons from underlaying raster layers

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.1, polygon

In ArcGIS 10.1, I have two layers:
1) raster of Topographic Wetness Index
2) vector layer of polygons representing soil types

I am wondering how to accomplish what I am after, that is to get information for polygons from the underling raster. In other words, I would like to extract the mean TWI for each polygon in order to calculate  what is (on average) the TWI for each soil type.

Answer (score 3):

With the Spatial Analyst Extension, using [Zonal Statistics as Table](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Zonal_Statistics_as_Table/009z000000w8000000/) should give you what you need.

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. May be my question was not clear. It is my understanding that extract by polygon will 'cut' the raster according to the polygons. What I am after is extract the mean value per each polygon from the underlying raster. Something similar to what 'add surface information' does in relation, e.g., to the polygons mean z (i.e., elevation). Instead of z, I would like to have the mean value of the TWI raster. I hope my poor English will not lead you astray.

Comment: @Maksim you are right with zonal stat, but not with extract by polygon. You should edit your answer with your comment to make things more readable.

Comment: @radouxju edited